# Printing ggplots out of list does not work in knitr with rmarkdown

Tags: r, compilation, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to put ggplots into a list and then later print each one in the list. That should be done with rmarkdown and knitr in RStudio. MWE (of course, in real, the list gets filled somewhere else than printed):

````
---
title: "nice title"
author: "Me"
date: 12\. Januar 2016
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_width: 7
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document: default
---

Here is my plot:

```{r, echo=F}
library(ggplot2)
printGGlist <- function(gglist){
for(gg in gglist){

    print(gg)

  }
}
g1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, cut)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, cut)) + geom_density()
gg <- list(g1, g2)
printGGlist(gg)
```
more text
````

The LaTeX code I get is however

```
\includegraphics{MyProject_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-7-1.pdf}!
\href{MyProject_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-7-2.pdf}{}!
\href{MyProject_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-7-3.pdf}{}!
```

Of course the result is not pretty. What happended here?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but it it works fine if you replace `printGGlist(gg)` with `lapply(gg, function(x) x)`.

Comment: Also, specifying  `fig.align='center'` works as well.

Comment: @toldo: That worked - but why did the other thing not work?

Comment: I also needed to set `results='hide'` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug recently introduced in **knitr** 1.12, and I have fixed it in the development version (>= 1.12.2): https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation

Comment: I guess it is to be installed with `devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr')`, right? If so, please add it to your post in order to help inexperienced readers ;-). Also: Please mention how stable the development version is otherwise.

Comment: The link will take you to the installation instructions now. Normally the development version is very stable. I don't push immature code to the repo, and there are a lot of tests in the package.