# plots not being printed in for loop when rendering PDF (since ggplot2 update)

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

I am attempting to render a PDF in which plots are outputted in a loop. The code I'm using previously worked as expected but now only the first plot in the loop is being printed in the pdf. The problem may be linked to the ggplot2 update (although I am not sure).

Below I have provided a reproducible example (as my rmarkdown file is far too long) which performs with the same error - printing only the first plot in the loop.

I may be missing something completely obvious of course! Any help greatly appreciated.

````
---
title: "Check"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r, results='asis'}
library(ggplot2)
Values = names(mtcars)[1:4]
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
for(v in Values){
 print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=carb, y = v, shape=gear)) + geom_point())
}
```

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] HH_3.1-24           gridExtra_2.0.0     multcomp_1.4-1      TH.data_1.0-6       survival_2.38-3     mvtnorm_1.0-3       latticeExtra_0.6-26
 [8] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-33     stringr_1.0.0       pander_0.6.0        xtable_1.8-0        ggplot2_2.0.0       rmarkdown_0.9.2    
[15] markdown_0.7.7      knitr_1.12         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.7-12       reshape2_1.4.1   splines_3.2.3    colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3    yaml_2.1.13      gmp_0.5-12       foreign_0.8-66  
 [9] Rmpfr_0.6-0      plyr_1.8.3       munsell_0.4.2    gtable_0.1.2     leaps_2.9        codetools_0.2-14 evaluate_0.8     labeling_0.3    
[17] httpuv_1.3.3     lmtest_0.9-34    vcd_1.4-1        proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.12.0      acepack_1.3-3.3  scales_0.3.0     formatR_1.2.1   
[25] Hmisc_3.16-0     abind_1.4-3      mime_0.4         digest_0.6.9     stringi_1.0-1    shiny_0.13.0     tools_3.2.3      sandwich_2.3-3  
[33] magrittr_1.5     Formula_1.2-1    cluster_2.0.3    MASS_7.3-45          R6_2.1.0         rpart_4.1-10     nnet_7.3-11 R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] HH_3.1-24           gridExtra_2.0.0     multcomp_1.4-1      TH.data_1.0-6       survival_2.38-3     mvtnorm_1.0-3       latticeExtra_0.6-26
 [8] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-33     stringr_1.0.0       pander_0.6.0        xtable_1.8-0        ggplot2_2.0.0       rmarkdown_0.9.2    
[15] markdown_0.7.7      knitr_1.12         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.7-12       reshape2_1.4.1   splines_3.2.3    colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3    yaml_2.1.13      gmp_0.5-12       foreign_0.8-66  
 [9] Rmpfr_0.6-0      plyr_1.8.3       munsell_0.4.2    gtable_0.1.2     leaps_2.9        codetools_0.2-14 evaluate_0.8     labeling_0.3    
[17] httpuv_1.3.3     lmtest_0.9-34    vcd_1.4-1        proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.12.0      acepack_1.3-3.3  scales_0.3.0     formatR_1.2.1   
[25] Hmisc_3.16-0     abind_1.4-3      mime_0.4         digest_0.6.9     stringi_1.0-1    shiny_0.13.0     tools_3.2.3      sandwich_2.3-3  
[33] magrittr_1.5     Formula_1.2-1    cluster_2.0.3    MASS_7.3-45 R6_2.1.0         rpart_4.1-10     nnet_7.3-11
````

[image: PDF output]

Comment: Could be the same bug as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768660/printing-ggplots-out-of-list-does-not-work-in-knitr-with-rmarkdown I suggest you try the development version of `knitr` and report whether that helps.

Comment: Installing the development version of `knitr` appears to fix the issue: `devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr', build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry @CL I think you guys are probably right about the knitr bug, but I haven't been able to test it as I don't have the permissions necessary to install Rtools on my computer (I've tried setting R_TOOLS_PATH = C:\Users\rfitzge6\Desktop\Rtools\bin;C:\Users\rfitzge6\Desktop\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin, but unfortunately this hasn't worked). I assume once I get around this the development version will probably work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Please see my comment above, I could only tag one user!

Comment: If you cannot install RTools, what about `update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.org');install.packages('knitr', repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.org'))` as described [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation)?

Comment: Hi @CL. when I try that I get this error: Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Hey so you guys are right about the knitr bug being the issue, so if someone wants to leave there comment as an answer I can select it! @CL. Also for anyone else facing the same issue who is unable/unwilling to download the developmental version adding cat('\n\n') after the print command is a workaround for the bug!

Comment: @Rae51 As the (IMHO) most valuable peace of information in this question is the workaround you found, I suggest you self-answer this question and accept your own answer.

Comment: @CL. okay will do, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by CL. and JasonAizkalns, a knitr bug is the issue, so downloading the developmental version of knitr should fix the issue.

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.org')
install.packages('knitr', repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.org'))
```

OR

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr', build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Also for anyone else facing the same issue who is unable/unwilling to download the developmental version adding cat('\n\n') after the print command is a workaround for the bug!

i.e.

```
for(v in Values){
 print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=carb, y = v, shape=gear)) + geom_point())
 cat('\n\n')
}
```